# R - rbind multiple dataframes in list based on pattern in dataframe name

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes (list) with the following names

```
names(list) <- c("prefix-001A","prefix-01B","prefix-001C","prefix-002A","prefix02B")
```

I want to create a new list of data frames with the following names:

```
new_list <- c("prefix-001","prefix-002")
```

"prefix-001" should be a dataframe that contains all the rows from the original dataframes "prefix-001A", "prefix01B", "prefix-001C", so those that contain the "001" or "01" in their name.

"prefix-002" should be a dataframe that contains all the rows from the original dataframes "prefix-002A" and "prefix-02B, so those that contain the "002" or "02" in their name.

I know that the data frames can be merged with rbind (they all have the same columns). But I don't know how I can select the correct dataframes for rbind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find out which list have `"01"` in their names using `grepl` (`vals`). We then create a new list, one with all `vals` index together and the other one without them and assign them names.

```
vals <- grepl("01", names(list_df))
setNames(list(do.call(rbind, list_df[vals]), 
              do.call(rbind, list_df[!vals])), new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first create two new objects from subsetting the original list and use `dplyr`'s `bind_rows()` to bind the data.frames in the orginial list:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2)

list_df <- list(df, df, df, df, df)

names(list) <- c("prefix-001A","prefix-01B","prefix-001C","prefix-002A","prefix02B")

library(dplyr)
"prefix-001" <- list[grep("prefix-00{0,1}1", names(list))] %>% 
  bind_rows()

"prefix-002" <- list[grep("prefix-{0,1}00{0,1}2", names(list))] %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Then you can combine the two objects into a new list.

```
new_list <- list(`prefix-001`, `prefix-002`)
```