# Average two dataframes together based on a shared prefix for multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a list of dataframes in R. Within this list, each dataframe is part of a "pair". You can tell which two dataframes go together because the names of the two dataframes share the same prefix (e.g., "001"), but they have different suffixes (e.g., "_AB", "_CD"). All the data within the dataframes is numeric (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) except for the identifier variable (`idvar`).

```
set.seed(12345)
library(dplyr)

# randomly generate a list of dataframes
# that looks like my real life data
id_vars <- gl(n = 30, k = 2) %>% sprintf("%03d", .)
mystrings <- rep.int(x = c("_AB", "_CD", "_EF", "_GH", "_IJ"), 60/5)
df_names <- paste0(id_vars, mystrings)

the_problem <- replicate(60, {
  data.frame(col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)),
             col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)),
             col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE))
             )
}, simplify = FALSE)

names(the_problem) <- df_names
```

I want to arithmetically average each "pair" of dataframes together. Once the two dataframes have been averaged together, the information contained in the suffix isn't important anymore, so I don't want that to be included in the final product. I also would like the final product to be a list of dataframes, not one big dataframe.

```
# how I'd like the final product to be structured
the_solution <- replicate(30, {
  data.frame(col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)),
             col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)),
             col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE))
  )
}, simplify = FALSE)

new_id <- gl(n = 30, k = 1) %>% sprintf("%03d", .)
the_solution <- mapply(cbind, the_solution, "idvar" = new_id, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
names(the_solution) <- new_id
```

I found [this prior SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971235/r-rbind-multiple-dataframes-in-list-based-on-pattern-in-dataframe-name) with a similar problem that involves dataframes sharing prefixes, but the solution isn't great when I have 30+ unique prefixes. Is there a way to accomplish this without having to mention each unique prefix?

Comment: To clarify, the average you want are the values from the same location? For example, ``mean(the_problem$`001_AB`$col1[1], the_problem$`001_CD`$col1[1])``, right?

Comment: @LMc, yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the list of data frames by their prefix and use `reduce` to compute the mean:

```
library(tidyverse)

name <- names(the_problem)
set_names(unique(str_extract(name, "^\\d+"))) |> 
map(~ the_problem[startsWith(name, .x)]) |> 
  imap(~ mutate(reduce(.x, `+`) / length(.x), idvars = .y))
```

**Output**

```
$`001`
   col1 col2 col3 idvars
1   3.0  1.0  2.5    001
2   1.5  3.0  3.0    001
3   2.5  3.5  2.5    001
4   3.5  1.5  4.5    001
5   3.5  3.5  2.5    001
6   2.5  3.5  2.5    001
7   2.5  1.5  3.0    001
8   3.0  4.5  4.0    001
9   3.5  3.5  2.5    001
10  2.0  3.5  4.0    001

$`002`
   col1 col2 col3 idvars
1   3.5  4.0  2.0    002
2   3.5  4.0  2.5    002
3   3.5  3.0  4.0    002
4   2.5  4.0  3.0    002
5   3.0  3.5  3.0    002
6   1.5  2.5  3.5    002
7   3.0  3.5  2.5    002
8   3.5  3.5  3.5    002
9   1.5  3.0  3.5    002
10  1.5  3.5  4.5    002
.
.
.
```

Alternatively, you could collapse everything into a big data frame, do the operation, and then split it apart:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

the_problem |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "x") |>
  mutate(rn = row_number(), .by = x) |>
  separate(x, into = c("idvars", "suffix")) |> 
  summarize(across(starts_with("col"), mean),
            .by = c(idvars, rn)) |> 
  select(-rn) |> 
  group_split(id_vars)
```

Comment: When I use this code, for some reason the `idvar` variable isn't correct in the output. For example, dataframe `001` contains `idvar` values for `001`, `007`, `013`, `019` and `025`.

Comment: @jrcalabrese I updated my solution and added another possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
prefixes = unique(id_vars)
result = lapply(prefixes, \(prefix) {
  i = grep(prefix, names(the_problem))
  Reduce(f = "+", the_problem[i]) / length(i)
  })

names(result) = prefixes
result[["001"]]
#    col1 col2 col3
# 1   3.0  5.0  4.0
# 2   3.0  2.0  2.5
# 3   3.0  2.5  2.0
# 4   5.0  2.5  3.0
# 5   3.0  2.5  1.5
# 6   2.0  2.0  2.5
# 7   2.0  5.0  3.0
# 8   3.5  1.0  5.0
# 9   4.0  3.0  4.0
# 10  2.5  3.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a `Mean` function and a `prefix` vector and then use `tapply`.  No packages are used.

```
Mean <- function(x) Reduce(`+`, x) / length(x)
prefix <- sub("_.*", "", names(the_problem))
tapply(the_problem, prefix, Mean, simplify = FALSE)
```

If we knew that there were always 2 objects to average we could alternatively define `Mean` as one of these:

```
Mean <- function(x) (x[[1]] + x[[2]]) / 2

Mean <- function(x) do.call(`+`, x) / 2
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this approach while maintaining `idvar` as a column within each dataframe?

Comment: Very nice! I never think to use `tapply` on `list` inputs.

Comment: @jrcalabrese, I am not clear on what you are referring to. There is no `idvar` column in any of the data frames in `the_problem`.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

interim <- rbindlist(lapply(the_problem, setDT, keep.rownames = TRUE), idcol = "idvar")
interim[, cohort := sub('(.*?)_.*', '\\1', idvar)]
avg_cols <- c("col1","col2","col3")

avg_dt <- interim[,lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = avg_cols, by = .(cohort, rn)]
split(avg_dt, avg_dt$cohort)
```

Can be extended to multiple average columns (by chaging `avg_cols`), different functions (by changing the function in `lapply(.SD)` and varying id structures (by modifying the regex)